# I want to display the jobs running on different clusters using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables job table and cluster table.Every cluster will have the different sub clusters.

LIKE
Main cluster

```
cluster1     cluster2      cluster3
--------------------------------------
job1         job15           job 20
.              .
.
.
j14
```

1st cluster will have 14 jobs 
2nd cluster will have 5 jobs
3rd cluster will have 5 jobs

Now I want to display the jobs running on different clusters (Including sub clusters) using PostgreSQL.

My table structure as follows

```
CREATE TABLE clusterdata(  
   clusterid bigint NOT NULL,
   sourceclustername character varying NOT NULL,
   clustername character varying NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE  job(
   clusterid bigint NOT NULL,
   jobname character varying NOT NULL,  
   sourcecluster bigint
);
```

Please help me...Thanx in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want your data formatted.. `select * from cluster` will give you all jobs on all clusters...

Comment: please provide minimal information on the database schema. are you using a resource manager such as SLURM ?

Comment: I want my data to be displayed like cluster name and sub clustername associated with that cluster and Jobs running in the subclusters....Means In a hierarchical structure.I am using Postgress..Sorry for the Incomplete Info

Comment: pls post sample data (insert into ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your sentence "1st cluster will have 14 jobs 2nd cluster will have 5 jobs 3rd cluster will have 5 jobs"
you can use something like this:

```
WITH BASE AS (
        SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sourcecluster, clusterid ORDER BY clusterid, jobname) AS RN
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sourcecluster  ORDER BY clusterid) * CASE WHEN sourcecluster=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS RN_GROUP
        FROM job )
      SELECT A.clusterid AS SOURCE_CLUSTER, A.jobname AS CLUSTER_1
      , B.jobname AS CLUSTER_2
      , C.jobname AS CLUSTER_3
      FROM BASE A      
      LEFT JOIN BASE B ON B.sourcecluster = A.clusterid AND B.RN_group=1 AND A.RN=B.RN   
      LEFT JOIN BASE C ON C.sourcecluster = A.clusterid AND C.RN_group=2 AND B.RN=C.RN
      WHERE A.sourcecluster=0
      ORDER BY A.clusterid, A.RN, B.RN;
```

Output:

```
    source_cluster  cluster_1   cluster_2   cluster_3
1   1               job1    job15   job20
2   1               job2    job16   job21
3   1               job3    job17   job22
4   1               job4    job18   NULL
5   1               job5    NULL    NULL
6   4               job41   NULL    NULL
7   4               job42   NULL    NULL
8   4               job43   NULL    NULL
9   4               job44   NULL    NULL
10  4               job45   NULL    NULL
11  5               job51   job55   NULL
12  5               job52   job56   NULL
13  5               job53   job57   NULL
14  5               job54   job58   NULL
15  5               job55   NULL    NULL
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO clusterdata VALUES (1, '0', 'clust1');
INSERT INTO clusterdata VALUES (2, 'clust1', 'clust1.1');
INSERT INTO clusterdata VALUES (3, 'clust1', 'clust1.2');
INSERT INTO clusterdata VALUES (4, '0', 'clust2');
INSERT INTO clusterdata VALUES (5, '0', 'clust3');
INSERT INTO clusterdata VALUES (6, 'clust3', 'clust3.1');

INSERT INTO job VALUES (1,'job1',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (1,'job2',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (1,'job3',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (1,'job4',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (1,'job5',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (2,'job15',1);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (2,'job16',1);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (2,'job17',1);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (2,'job18',1);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (3,'job20',1);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (3,'job21',1);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (3,'job22',1);

INSERT INTO job VALUES (4,'job41',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (4,'job42',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (4,'job43',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (4,'job44',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (4,'job45',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (5,'job51',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (5,'job52',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (5,'job53',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (5,'job54',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (5,'job55',0);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (6,'job55',5);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (6,'job56',5);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (6,'job57',5);
INSERT INTO job VALUES (6,'job58',5);
```

Comment: it's just an alias of a column... I suggest to try the query using a small data set (mine, for example).

Comment: Thanxs..Its usefull